# Updating django result_list fields timezone

Tags: python, django

I have a model with a `click_time` field that is a `DateTimeField`. In my admin it is displayed as `UTC`.

My goal is to display the `click_time` in the admin as the logged in users timezone, which is being set in the field `user.userprofile.timezone`.

Currently I created a capture tag that looks like this

```
from django import template
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def convert_time(user_timezone, click_time):
    time = datetime.strptime(click_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    local_tz = pytz.timezone(user_timezone)
    user_time = time.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc).astimezone(local_tz)

    return user_time
```

Also I have created a `admin/app/change_list.html` that looks like this

```
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}
{% load i18n admin_static admin_list %}
{% load capture_tags %}

{% block result_list %}
  {% if action_form and actions_on_top and cl.full_result_count %}{% admin_actions %}{% endif %}
    {% result_list cl %}
  {% if action_form and actions_on_bottom and cl.full_result_count %}{% admin_actions %}{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

My question is how can I apply my `convert_time` tag to the `result_list` cl? Or is there a better way to go about doing this?

Comment: Call [`activate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.activate) in your view and the `DateTimeFields` will automatically be converted to the desired time zone.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work since I have to get the timezone from the userprofile

Comment: Why is that a problem? The user is attached to the request object that is passed to views. Or you could do it with [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#selecting-the-current-time-zone). There are various ways to do it, but the basic idea is simple: get the timezone from the logged-in user's profile, then `activate()` it.